# about when_any Function (C++ REST SDK)

Tags: c++, casablanca

here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj969480.aspx

the code is like this

```
template<typename _Iterator>
auto when_any(_Iterator _Begin, _Iterator _End, const task_options& _TaskOptions = task_options())
-> decltype (details::_WhenAnyImpl<typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::value_type::result_type, _Iterator>::_Perform(_TaskOptions, _Begin, _End))
{
       typedef typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::value_type::result_type _ElementType;
       return details::_WhenAnyImpl<_ElementType, _Iterator>::_Perform(_TaskOptions, _Begin, _End);
}
```

my question is

```
 typedef typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::value_type::result_type _ElementType;
```

where is result_type coming from?

thanks a lot

Comment: [See the Casablanca docs **here**](http://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classpplx_1_1task.html).

Comment: so, it seems std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::value_type should be task,

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

Looks like `std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::value_type` should be correct.

Comment: @graham.reeds: Actually, he's putting the answer he found as an answer, which is _absolutely the correct thing to do_. (He hasn't done it very well, though.) **Answers do not go in the comments section.**

Comment: @graham.reeds I just reframed the wording of the answer and now it is an answer.